# Unit Test Specific Rows in a Datasource

Tags: c#, unit-testing

MSTest automatically iterates a unit test per the amount of rows in a data source, in my case Excel. I want to use the same data source, but stop the iteration at a certain row for certain tests. For example:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
[DeploymentItem("muhExcelFile.xlsx")]
[DataSource("muhExcelDataSource")]
[TestMethod]
public void UseAllRowsInThisMethod()
{
//Test All rows
}

[DeploymentItem("muhExcelFile.xlsx")]
[DataSource("muhExcelDataSource")]
[TestMethod]
public void UseOnlyTheFirstRowInThisOne()
{
//Just test the first row
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set a condition on the test all rows method:

```
[DeploymentItem("muhExcelFile.xlsx")]
[DataSource("muhExcelDataSource")]
[TestMethod]
public void UseAllRowsInThisMethod()
{

    if(rowVariable == testCondition)
    {
        //perform test
    }


}
```